# Is there an EF 5 equivalent of nhibernate's IIdentifierGenerator?

Tags: nhibernate, entity-framework-5, key-generator

I know in EF you can specify that a PK is generated by a db (like MSSQL identity), but are there any hooks here? Is there a way to plug in a custom pk generator like in NHibernate with the IIdentifierGenerator interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no. EF does not have that kind of extensibility.

Long answer: you might be able to emulate that by overriding `SaveChanges` or listening to `ObjectContext.SavingChanges`, getting the newly added entities from the tracker and assigning ids.